# python program related to strings

Tags: python, string

Ask the user to enter T or S or R. If the entered string is T then print formula of
the area of the triangle. If the entered string is S then print formula of the area of
the square. If it is R then print formula of the area of the rectangle.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Please read [ask].

Comment: So, are you expecting us to do your homework?

Comment: No code writing service is available here. Please add the code you have tried and then ask for help

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

while(True):
    print('T: formula of the area of the triangle \n S: formula of the area of the square \n R: formula of the area of the rectangle \n')
    x = raw_input('Enter your option: ')

    if str(x.upper()) == 'T':
       print "area = h*b/2 \n"
    elif str(x.upper()) == 'S':
       print "area = a*a \n"
    elif str(x.upper()) == 'R':
       print "area = w*l \n"
    else:
       print "Please enter a valied input \n"
```

here you go